# YII framework Create A Contact Form To Send Mail To Email Id Of Another Model's Entry

Tags: php, email, yii

i have a form to store values for a model add having rows id name description and one is email to store email for particular entry.

Now i want a contact form to send mail for that particular model values...

that is to send mail to the owner of particular add..

I able to reuse contact form for that purpose but i fail to fetch saved email id for each add so that any viewer can mail for adds..

How to achive this task?? please help me someone..

let me know the how can i do this??

if any example code will be very useful to me..

Thank you.....

Comment: your problem is not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search the db if there is a matching email address

In your contact form processing controller

```
$model = Contacts::model()->findByAttributes(
              'email'=>$_POST['ContactForm']['email_address'])

if (!is_null($model))
   ... send mail ...
else 
   Yii::app()->user->setFlash('error','That email address is not registered');
```